# Task Scheduler - Run a process every hour except at designated time

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2

I'd like to schedule to run a particular process at 40 minutes on hourly basis, except on Sunday at 2:40AM.

How would one set up the trigger for this in Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up multiple triggers in Windows Scheduler. One "Weekly" trigger recurring for 6 Days. A second "Weekly" trigger (Sunday), which will repeat its task every hour for a duration of 23 hours (you don't have to use the pre-defined times, just type new ones into the field). Set start times accordingly to meet your requirements.